# Aerospike update record using secondary index

Tags: aerospike

How to update record in aerospike using secondary index.
Is it possible using c client ???.
Or else can I get PK using secondary index which later can be used to update record.I am using aerospike c client.

Answer (score 0):

So indexes are created on Bins (Columns in RDBMS terminologies) So assuming you have created Secondary index on one of your bin. it's possible to update record on that bases.

So,here is the approach i know that i would suggest

1. Grab all the Records (Rows) using select query and applying where on secondary index
2. So that way you have all the Records with unique key
3. Go ahead and update those keys with the values you want

So for query reference use [This](https://www.aerospike.com/docs/guide/single.html)

And yes it is Possible to do it using C client Check [This](https://www.aerospike.com/docs/client/c/usage/query/query.html)